# maximizing a summation.

Tags: summation, discrete-optimization

Suppose we have $n$ nodes and $T_i(n):=$ number of visits to a node $i$ till time $n$. I have the following discrete summation, which I want to maximize:
$$
\max_{\substack{ T_i(n) \\ 1 \leq i \leq k} }  \sum_{i=1}^k  \sum_{j=1}^{T_i(n)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{j} } \,\,\,\,\text{s.t.} \,\,\,\,\sum_{i=1}^k T_i(n) = n,
$$
For instance for $k=2$, this would be maximizing
$$\Bigg(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{T_1(n)}}\Bigg) + \Bigg(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{T_2(n)}}\Bigg)$$
I have the intuition that the above is maximized at $T_i(n) = \frac{n}{k},\,\forall \,i$. Is there any way to rigorously prove this for any finite $k$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it appears that the maximum occurs when $T_i(n) \in \{\lfloor n/k \rfloor, \lceil n/k \rceil\}$ for all $i$.  To prove this, you could show that any solution not of this form can be improved.  For example, suppose $T_i(n) < \lfloor n/k \rfloor$ for some $i$, and modify the solution by increasing $T_i(n)$ by $1$ and decreasing some other $T_j(n) > \lfloor n/k \rfloor$ by $1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I actually used the integral test to bound the summations by \sqrt(T_i(n)). The resultant function (being concave) can be see n to have a maximum at $T_i(n) =T_j(n)$.

Comment: But bounded by a concave function does not necessarily mean that the original function is concave.

Comment: Yes that is true (it will actually be also lower bounded by it), but I am only interested in upper bounding it.